# Скачать файл с другого сайта по url и загрузить по ftp

Tags: php

Есть ссылка на файл, хочу его загрузить на другой сервер (не тот, с которого запускаю `PHP` скрипт) по ftp.

Файл из ссылки можно передать в `ftp_put()` ?

Answer (score -1):

Конечно, например с помощью этой функции:

```
<?php

function uploadFTP($server, $username, $password, $local_file, $remote_file)
{
    // connect to server
    $connection = ftp_connect($server);

    // login
    if (@ftp_login($connection, $username, $password)){
        // successfully connected
    }else{
        return false;
    }

    ftp_put($connection, $remote_file, $local_file, FTP_BINARY);
    ftp_close($connection);
    return true;
}
```

Использование:

```
uploadFTP("127.0.0.1", "admin", "mydog123", 
          "C:\\report.txt", "meeting/tuesday/report.txt");
```

Если нужно скачать файл по ссылке - то для этого подойдет функция file_get_contents($url)

```
file_put_contents("report.txt", fopen("http://someurl/report.txt", 'r'));
```

Comment: При попытке сохранить, говорит, что на сервере, куда сохраняю, нет файла test.txt. Message: ftp_put(test.txt): failed to open stream: No such file or directory

Comment: Похоже, что с удаленного сервера он загружать не хочет :(